# How can i add a post build step to an existing job using job dsl?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

How can i add a post build step to an existing job using job dsl ? 
Note: I need to append to the existing job. It should not delete the existing steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can not append something to an existing job. You need to code the complete job definition in Job DSL.

But you can use the Jenkins API to add a post build step:

```
FreeStyleProject job = Jenkins.instance.getItem('job-a')
job.publishersList << new hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger('job-b', false)
```

You can try the code in Jenkins Script Console.

Note that a post build step will be added each time you run the script. If you code the complete job definition in Job DSL, the Job DSL engine will modify the job only if the script changed or your job configuration does not match the definition.

Comment: Thanks Ill try that :)